# blue screen error upon external disk connection

Tags: external-hard-drive, bsod

In Windows 7 enterprise edition, When I connect my 1 TB external disk, famous blue screen error comes up and my computer restarts immediately.

I want to fix my external hard disk. What is your suggestion?

I don't have any problem with this external hard disk in Ubuntu.

I want to completely format the hard disk and make some sort of factory reset.

Edit1: I format the External memory with Gparted but still windows crush. I even tried safe mode and it crush anyway.

As a newbie, I dont know other tools in Ubuntu so what else can be done?

Edit2: Dmp file in C:\Windows\Minidump is uloaded [here](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/021516-28080-01).

BSOD message:

> A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart
>   your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to be sure you have adequate disk space. If a driver is
>   identified in the Stop message, disable the driver or check with the
>   manufacturer for driver updates. Try changing video adapters.
>
> Check with your hardware vendor for any BIOS updates. Disable BIOS
>   memory options such as caching or shadowing. If you need to use Safe
>   Mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press F8
>   to select Advanced Startup options, and then select Safe Mode.
>
> Technical information:
>
> *** STOP: 0x0000007e (some other 0x numbers)
>
> Collecting data for crash dump ...
>
> Initializing data for crash dump ...
>
> Beginning dump of physical memory.
>
> bumping physical memory to disk :  40

Comment: Why don't you launch the Disk Utility in Ubuntu to format the drive?

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: I add message of BSOD and bmp file

Comment: @root which disk utility you recommend?

Comment: "Disk Utility" which ships with Ubuntu.

Comment: Disk utility solved the problem. tnx. btw, why negative vote? this problem can happend for others. what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows crashes while reading the drive layout (partmgr!PmGetDriveLayoutEx):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem. 
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000094, The exception code that was not handled


00 nt!FstubReadHeaderEFI
01 nt!FstubReadPartitionTableEFI
02 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'
03 partmgr!PmGetDriveLayoutEx
04 partmgr!PmFilterDeviceControl
05 nt!IopCreateArcName
06 partmgr!PmStartDevice
07 partmgr!PmPnp
08 nt!PnpAsynchronousCall
09 nt!PnpStartDevice
0a nt!PnpStartDeviceNode
0b nt!PipProcessStartPhase1
0c nt!PipProcessDevNodeTree
```

I see that you still use the original Sp1 without any updates.

> BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.17514.amd64fre.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850

Run Windows Update and if you have installed updates, try again. Also try Linux tools to detect/fix disk issues. If Windows crashes at detecting the partitions, the drive has issues.